# Send warning messages to Sentry (react-native-sentry)

Tags: javascript, sentry, react-native-sentry

I have include Sentry to track crashes of my mobile application. It is working properly, now I want to send warning messages to sentry to track them. Is there a way to do this from JavaScript side. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// set a custom message
Sentry.captureMessage("TEST message", {
  level: SentrySeverity.Warning
}); // Default SentrySeverity.Error
```

There's a lot of available methods highlight in the [React Native config docs](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/react-native/config/).